# Why am I not able to include header file from cmake exported/imported library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to write a header only library to be imported by others, using CMake. I tried to follow the instructions by Daniel Pfeifer - "Effective CMake". However I am not able to include the header files into another project. For illustration purpose I created a similar toy project having the tree structure:

```
├── testinclude
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── testinclude.cpp
└── testlib
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── testLib.h
└── testLibConfig.cmake
```

while the library is supposed to be testLib.h containing

```
void sayHello(){
    std::cout<<"Hello"<<'\n';
}
```

and the source code for the executable testinclude.cpp looks like:

```
#include"testLib.h"

int main(){
    sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to follow Daniel Pfeifers guidelines my CMakeLists.txt in the directory testlib looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(testLib VERSION 0.1)

add_library(testLib INTERFACE )

target_include_directories(testLib INTERFACE 
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

install(TARGETS testLib EXPORT testLibTargets
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
install(EXPORT testLibTargets
    FILE testLibTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE testLib::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/testLib
)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file("testLibConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION ${testLib_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)
install(FILES "testLibConfig.cmake" "testLibConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/testLib
)
```

and testLibConfig.cmake:

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/testLibTargets.cmake")
```

end finally the CMakeLists.txt in the directory testinclude:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(testInclude)

add_executable(testInclude testinclude.cpp)

find_package(testLib)
target_link_libraries(testInclude PRIVATE testLib::testLib)
```

After running in the directory testlib:

```
cmake .
sudo make install
```

and running in the testinclude directory:

```
cmake .
make
```

I get the error that testLib.h was not found, even though I had no complains or error before.

Comment: I don't see installation of `testLib.h` file by your header-only library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Tsyvarev was absolutely correct. Additionally installing the public header file "testLib.h" (into some location independent of the project) was the missing thing to do. 
Adding the line

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/testLib.h" DESTINATION
include/testLib )
```

to the "testLib/CMakeLists.txt"
fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your install doesn't include the header files.
use `set_target_properties(tgt PROPERTIEs PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADER_FILES}")`
and PUBLIC_HEADER in install to install them (warning no subdirectory allowed)

also "include DESTINATION" in install should not be use, try to use `target_include_directories()` instead ("includes" which is a reminiscence of pre Modern CMake). It is just need when you want to add install include directories...

Otherwise seems fine to me...
e.g. https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-cpp/blob/master/Foo/CMakeLists.txt
src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html

Comment: I'd suggest `target_sources` instead of setting the property directly: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_sources.html

Comment: Using the set_properties ansatz I get the error : INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The
  property "PUBLIC_HEADER" is not allowed.

Comment: IMHO target_sources list are source file to compile i.e. .cpp and for ide to display them, public_header is the only one integrated in the install command. so unless kitware fix consistency and add a install source destination which could be cool for header only library we are basically stuck